# Intelligent Comparison based Update - Access / VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

Need to intelligently perform updates on an access table.
Expert VBA / Intelligent Thinking would be required.

```
Table1 (For reference only)
CompanyCode     Text
RegionCategory  Number (1-99)
RegionCount     Number(0 - 25000)

Table2
InvoiceNumber       Number
CompanyCode         Text    
NumRows             Number
RegionCode          FourdigitNumber
ConfirmationRemark  Y / N
```

Ourobjective is to put a Yes or No in the 'ConfirmationRemark' Column.
Rules :

1.Select only those InvoiceNumbers which have exactly two rows from Table2 and different RegionCode. These will have the same CompanyCode. RegionCategory is first two digits of RegionCode.

2.For these two Invoices -  The difference between the two RegionCategory must be greater than two.

3.LookUp The RegionCount , from Table1

Decision Making :
We are now basically comparing two Invoices with different RegionCodes.
Idea is that , the Invoice with higher RegionCount is the one to be marked Yes.

1.The difference between RegionCount must be considerable. 'considerable' - I am trying to determine what would be the right number. Let us take 500 for now.

2.The Invoice with lower Region Count - should have RegionCount - Zero (bestCase) or very very low. If The Invoice with lower Region Count has a high RegionCount value > 200 , then we cannot successfully conclude.

3.NumRows , is prefered to be 1 or lesser than the other. This comparison , is not mandatory , hence we shall have a provision to not check for this. Mark the Other Invoice as 'N'

Comment: I am having difficulty even getting started , thats why gave a straught firward question. If some basic VBA code and query can be given here , I can start trying to figure it out , then again we can work on it. It may be challenging deal even for a VBA expert.

Comment: Why not start with #1, and see how it goes from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have many ways to approach that type of complex update.

If you are lucky, you may be able to craft a SQL `UPDATE` statement that can include all the changes, but often you will have to resort to a combination of `SELECT` queries and custom VBA to filter them based on the results of calculations or lookups involving other data.

#### A few hints

- Often, we tend to think about a problem in terms of 'what are the steps to get to the data that match the criteria'.
  Sometimes, though, it's easier to turn the problem on its head and instead ask yourself 'what are the steps to get to the data that do not match the criteria'.
  Because in your case the result is boolean, true or false, you could simply set the `ConfirmationRemark` field to `True` for all records and then update those that should be set to `False`, instead of the other way around.
- Break down each step (as you did) and try to find the simplest `SELECT` query that will return just the data you need for that step. If a step is too complex, break it down further.
- Compose your broken down `SELECT` statements together to slowly build a more complex query that tends toward your goal.
- Once you have gone as far as you can, either construct an `UPDATE Table2 SET ConfirmationRemark=True WHERE InvoiceNumber IN (SELECT InvoiceNumber ....)` or use VBA to go through the recordset of results from your complext `SELECT` statement and do some more checks before you update the field in code.

#### Some issues

Unfortunately, despite your efforts to document your situation, there are not enough details for us to really help:

- you do not mention which are the primary keys (from what you say, it seems that `Table2` could have multiple records with identical `InvoiceNumber`)
- the type of data you are dealing with is not obvious. You should include a sample of data and identify which ones should end-up with `ConfirmationRemark` set.
- your problem is really too localised, meaning it is too specific to your to be of value to anyone else, although I think that with a bit more details your question could be of interest, if only to show an example of how to approach complex data updates in Access.